# Complex-valued autoregressive and ARMA processes

Tags: time-series, autoregressive

I’m working with complex-valued discrete time series, and specifically with complex-valued autoregressive and ARMA processes.
Could someone provide me with some suggestions about a good papers or books on this topic?

Thanks in advance!